# R: Adding vertex attributes to a network (using statnet)

Tags: r, attributes, network-programming, social-networking

I'm currently doing a Network Analysis in R, using the Statnet package (http://statnet.csde.washington.edu/)

So far I have been able to:

1) Construct Social Networks using the network() function. The information I had was originally contained in a incidence matrix form (one row per project, project members in the columns), which I transformed to adjency (socio-matrix) form before building the networks in R.

2) Plot the networks and compute general statistics (both for the overall network and for network vertexes)

3) Add external vertex attributes to the networks

4) Plot the networks with vertexes in different colors according to their attributes.

Right now I would like to complement my analysis by adding edge attributes to the network (to differentiate relationships, for example different kinds of projects).

I know I can use the set.edge.attribute() function, and that I need to input a vector of the same size as the total of edges that exist in the network. However, I don't know exactly how to sort this vector of edge attributes, in order for the  function to assign them correctly to the corresponding edges.

Anybody knows how the network() function sorts edges internally? Any ideas on how to sort my vector of edge attributes in order to get a appropriate matching?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your question title refers to vertex attributes. your question refers to edge attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The `network()` function can create networks from various types of inputs (such as an edgelist or an adjacency matrix) so it would help if you gave a bit more of a code example explaining how you are creating the network and the format of the structure your edge attribute data are in.

I believe that in general `network()` will create the edges in the same order as the input edgelist.  So if your edge attribute vector is in the same order as your original data, you should be able to use `set.edge.attribute()` safely.  If your edge attributes are in a matrix form, you can use `set.edge.value()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Skyebend! I modified my code to construct the network using an edgelist (rather than a incidence matrix) and I was able to assign the edge attributes correctly that way.